# Empty JSON response when trying to parse JSONObject with one JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I got code that gets `JSONArrays`, but however when I try to get `JSONObject` that contains only one `JSONArray` it gives me empty `JSONArray`.

For example if I need to get data from this `JSONObject`:

```
{"events":[{"start":1357714800,"end":1357736400,"name":"Example1","description":""}]}
```

I get `{"events":[]}` as `JSONObject`, `[]` meaning that it doesn't contain any JSONArrays. Also length of `JSONObject` is in this case 0. But it doesn't throw any kind of `Exceptions`.

but if `JSONObject` contains multiple `JSONArrays` like this:

```
{"events":[{"start":1357714800,"end":1357736400,"name":"Example1","description":""},{"start":1357714600,"end":1357736500,"name":"Example2","description":""},{"start":1357514800,"end":1357536400,"name":"Example3","description":""}]}
```

then my code works perfect.

Here is the code I use to parse JSON:

```
private void getObjects(String url) throws JSONException, Exception {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new NetTask().execute(url).get());
        JSONArray job1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("events");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
        System.out.println("JOB1 LENGTH: "+job1.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < job1.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonEvent = job1.getJSONObject(i);
            int start = jsonEvent.getInt("start");
            int end = jsonEvent.getInt("end");
            String name = jsonEvent.getString("name");
            String description = jsonEvent.getString("description");
        }
    }

    public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String jsonText = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int read;
                char[] chars = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                    buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
                }

                jsonText = buffer.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return jsonText;
        }
    }
```

is there something wrong that I am missing or is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Try Logging the Json text you receive from the web, just to make sure all that stuff is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your given code (though I just made the AsyncTask just return the single-array string, and had to replace the opptunti.getString() stuff with jsonEvent.getString()). It worked fine, aside from the fact that you're probably blocking the UI thread to wait for the server response.

My guess is the problem is that you are hitting the wrong URL, that the parameters are wrong or something like that.

Comment: "oppitunti" was typo. after you said URL is propably wrong I went and checked it and found out that all the "empty" arrays had space in their name for example url was something like this "/json%20array" and i was typing just "/json array" as string, so i think this solves my problem. thanks! btw do you know which method is faster, your AsyncTask that returns single array strings or mine that returns the whole string?

Comment: Oh, I meant that I just removed all of the network stuff and just returned the static string you listed (the one with the single array, as opposed to the one with multiple arrays) instead of hitting a web service. Glad it worked for you!